# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "and"

Tags: postgresql

I am getting this postgresql exception. This is my query:

```
select * from (\
  select \
   st.station_type_id as "id", \
     case when \
      ( \
        mast.station_type_desc is null \
      ) \
      then st.station_type_desc else mast.station_type_desc end as "description" \
      from station_type st left outer \
           join master_agent_station_type mast on st.station_type_id = mast.station_type_id \
      and mast.party_id='%s' where st.is_active='Y'\
) as result
```

I am new to postgresql.

Comment: Remove those backslashes they are invalid in an SQL statement

Comment: please quote whole error with position...